# Do std::tuple and std::pair support aggregate initialization?

Tags: c++, tuples, aggregate, std-pair, c++17

[Aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) requires among other things *no user-provided constructors*. But `std::tuple` and `std::pair` pair have a large set of [overloaded constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple). From the point of the core language, are these constructors *user-provided* or even *user-declared* ?

With C++17 it will be possible to write (update/clarification: where nocopy is a class that can not be copied or moved, such as `std::mutex`)

```
auto get_ensured_rvo_str(){
   return std::pair(std::string(),nocopy());
}
```

***edit: no, it's not possible as explained in the linked to answers and the answer below.***

which requires aggregate initialization (for context: [Multiple return values (structured bindings) with unmovable types and guaranteed RVO in C++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38385451/multiple-return-values-structured-bindings-with-unmovable-types-or-guaranteed)).

Are `tuple` and `pair` backed by special standard language to allow this (in presence of constructors) ? :

> 20.5.2.1 Construction
>
> ... 
>   EXPLICIT constexpr tuple(const Types&...);
>
> 6 
>   Effects: The
>   constructor initializes each element with the value of the
>   corresponding parameter.

or can we in principle write our own `tuple` or `pair`?

Comment: The current example doesn't require aggregate initialization. Please provide a relevant example.

Comment: @songyuanyao, @Alf, My reading of the linked to answers are that it's not possible to initialize uncopyable+unmovable members with an actual constructor like that, and that it's powered by aggregate initialization which is not really a constructor call. Also, clarified that `nocopy` is also unmovable (as in the linked question).

Comment: If I reading accepted answer correctly, it says that `pair` code will not work.

Comment: @Recover_Ocelot. Correct, and in line with the answer by ecatmur.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no support in `tuple` or `pair` for passing no-move types to their constructors, and as you've observed there cannot be, since the constructor argument and tuple (or pair) member **can be observed to be different objects**:

```
// exposition only
template<class... Us>
tuple(Us&&... us) : values{std::forward<Us>(us)...} {}
              ^^ these
                    ^^^^^^ are different objects to these
```

You would have to use piecewise construction:

```
return std::pair<std::string, nocopy>(std::piecewise_construct,
    std::forward_as_tuple(), std::forward_as_tuple());
```

Matt Calabrese made an [interesting point](https://isocpp.org/forums/iso-c-standard-future-proposals?place=msg%2Fstd-proposals%2FJ62lsMB6Egc%2F38M9WKYvCQAJ) on the std-proposals list that now we have guaranteed RVO it should be possible to write components that accept factories to construct their members effectively inplace:

```
// hypothetical factory constructor
return std::pair(std::factory_construct,
    [] { return std::string{}; }, [] { return nocopy{}; });
```

Another possible direction would be to remove the constructors from `tuple` and `pair` (or, more realistically, to write workalike components without constructors) and rely on the [new extensions to aggregate initialization](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0017r0.html) that should permit aggregate initialization of `tuple` and `pair` implemented via multiple-inheritance. [Example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/63SPQHgu1myz3Twi).

Comment: You are right for sure. It's pretty interesting as it opens up a use case for a plain aggregate without constructors as in the linked to question: `template<typename T1,typename T2,typename T3>
    struct many {
      T1 a;
      T2 b;
      T3 c;
    };
   template<class T1, class T2, class T3>
   many(T1, T2, T3) -> many<T1, T2, T3>;`.

Comment: I cannot help but think that the language is becoming too complex to use. With too many overlapping notations. It seems it started with C++14. :(

Comment: ectamur, as you refined your answer I wrote a follow up question which is quite related to your updates. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38393302/variadic-struct-and-variadic-template-construction-deduction-guide-in-c17

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: You don't have to know anything about this stuff to use the language. Immobile types not being able to be used with `pair` isn't even new; that's C++98 stuff. If you made your copy constructor go away, it wouldn't work. The only thing that has been made "complex" is that there are now cases where you *can* use immobile objects to initialize aggregates.

Comment: The factory construct bit is awkward.  Really, we need a way to efficiently and tersely express "this isn't a Foo, it is instructions on how to construct a Foo in a place of your choosing" as a function argument, *and* to write it on the calling side without having to write a lambda.